# I am getting None type object error but I do not know how and why it is occuring?

Tags: class, object, binary-tree

so I am writing a code for a binary tree and for some functions regardnig it, I am having some trouble running the code and I cannot figure out why this error is occuring.

```
def insertelement(self,n):
    newnode = Node(n)
    itr = self.root
    x = False
    if itr == None:
        self.root = newnode
    elif itr != None :
        while x is False:
            if itr.data > n:
                itr = itr.right
            elif itr.data < n:
                itr = itr.left
            elif ((itr.right == None) and itr.data > n):
                itr.right = newnode
            elif ((itr.left == None) and itr.data < n):
                itr.left = newnode
    else :
        return 0

def binarysearchfordatass(self,n):
    pppointer = self.root
    i = 0
    while pppointer.data != n:
        if pppointer.data < n:
            pppointer = pppointer.left
            i = i+1

        else:
            pppointer = pppointer.right
            i = i+1
    return i
```

when I run the following code I get an error message

> if itr.data > n:
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

so here as u can see in the code I already have an if statement which makes self.root = newnode if self.root is None, however I dont why the elif loop below it will execute on self.root if it is none since if it were none the if statement above it would have been executed.
Can someone please help me understand why this error is occuring ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into an infinite loop as you have set `x` to `False` and you are never updating `x` within the loop, thus the while condition is always `True`.
And yes you are checking if `itr == None` first but then you go into this inifinite loop and you might possibly be setting `itr` to `None` again in the first iteration of the loop and in the second iteration it will consequently then fail.

This is theoretically possible but you could easily find out what is actually going on by debugging your code and stepping through it line-by-line.

Comment: I have tried going thru it line by line but I am still not getting where the problem lies, I have changed my code multiple times and it still returns the error.(PS I have only changed the part of the code under the if else loop)